# Google Appscript - Handle multiple google account

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom form that makes a few requests to a database to verify the user. I noticed that if I have a single google account it works fine but it doesn't with multiple. The other thing I noticed is that the script doesn't throw any error it just doesn't communicate back the result from the custom form.

This is how my custom forms look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container select-client">
        <div class="client">Client</div>
        <select class="client-select">
            <option>Select Client</option>
            <!-- ...options -->
        </select>
        <div class="market">Market</div>
        <select class="market-select">
            <option>Select Market</option>
            <!-- ...options -->
        </select>
        <div class="error-message"></div>
        <button class="button" id="select-button" onclick="handleSelect()">Select</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        // ...code to validate the user
        function handleSelect() {
            var _client = clients.find(
                (client) => client.id === parseInt(selectedClient)
            );
            var _market = markets.find(
                (market) => market.id === parseInt(selectedMarkets)
            );

            if (!_client && !_market) {
                return;
            }

            if (!_client) {
                errorMessageClientMarket.innerHTML = 'Please select client';
                return;
            }

            if (!_market) {
                errorMessageClientMarket.innerHTML = 'Please select market';
                return;
            }

            google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler()
                .loginData({ token, market: _market, client: _client, user: userInfo, platform });

            google.script.host.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how I create the custom form using app script

```
const loginForm = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loginFormHtml')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(600);
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, `Login`);
};
```

This is the callback function:

```
const loginData = (data) => { // <--- this function is ignored when a the users has multiple google accounts
  console.log('LOGIN FORM');
  const { token, market, user, client, platform } = data;
  UserProperties.setProperty('token', token);
  UserProperties.setProperty('userId', user.id);
  UserProperties.setProperty('clientId', client.id);
  UserProperties.setProperty('clientName', client.name);
  UserProperties.setProperty('marketId', market.id);
  UserProperties.setProperty('marketName', market.code_name);
  UserProperties.setProperty('username', `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`);
  UserProperties.setProperty('userEmailAddress', user.email);
  UserProperties.setProperty('platform', platform);

  const info = UserProperties.getProperties();
  console.log('info ---> ', info)

  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  getMenu(true);
  ui.alert('Logged in Successfully');
};
```

Does anyone know if there's a away to fix this?

Comment: Is this script deployed as a web app?

Comment: it's not deployed yet, but it will be deployed as add.

Comment: Have you tried using the Apps Script debugger?